# Did DIO have two stands?

Tags: jojos-bizarre-adventure

So I was re-watching Jojo's bizarre adventures Part 3 stardust crusaders, and I was wondering.

> Does DIO have two stands? In the anime at least he appears to have a hermit purple, stand similar to Joseph's.

Was this in the manga as well? Or just an anime-only thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. He has his stand, named 'The World', and also the stand he gained from Jonathan's body, which doesn't have a name, but operates similarly to Joseph's Hermit Purple.

Comment: So was that second stand in the manga as well?

Comment: @DIO_OVA It was. You can read more about it on its JoJo Wiki page here: https://jojowiki.com/Jonathan%27s_Stand